# first time check in my pycharm project to Git

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I have written whole code before cloning any repo, now I decided to push entire code into new repo directly from pycharm IDE.

Do anyone know how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to push the project to GitHub, just use VCS - Import into Version control - Share on GitHub.

If you want to push somewhere else, then:

1. Use VCS - Enable VCS integration. If there is no git repository in
   the project, IDE will create one.
2. Mark all files you need, add them to git and commit
3. Add a remote using VCS - Git - Remotes
4. Push (VCS - Git - Push, or `Ctrl+Shift+K`)

Comment: What if I wanted to create another branch as a master is not the right place to check-in first, I wanted to create another feature branch.

Comment: If you want another branch, just create one. Right after the step 2

Comment: Yes, Thanks #Dmitriy I did create a new branch using, VCS => Git => Branches => Created "new branch"  and then checked-in and pushed into the new branch.

Answer (score -1):

1. first check your remote by git remote -v
2. add remote of new repo while creating repo you will get.
   git remote add origin
3. git init
4. git add .
5. git commit -m "first initialize"
6. git push origin master

Comment: I'm not sure this really answers the question, as the OP clearly says they want to do it directly from the IDE. These steps appear to be how to do it from a terminal.